# SessionSubmit + ScheduledTask is not working in wolframscript environment

Tags: scripting

I have, for example, the following scheduled task

```
SessionSubmit@ScheduledTask[
    Print["testing..."]
,{Quantity[1,"Seconds"],Infinity}]
```

which when you execute will print `testing...` every second indefinitely. The code works in the notebook environment as well as in the .wls script editor. But when you try to run it via `wolframscript test.wls` via terminal, nothing happens.

Why does this happen/how to make this run?